# How can I get look_at matrix from view_matrix?

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to set a `look_at` with the input of a view matrix, is there a way to do it?

Because I know you can do the opposite (I think) where you set a look at and get a view matrix.

Comment: To ensure there's no ambiguity or misunderstanding, can you define specifically what makes a matrix "look_at" vs "view"? Showing us how you're currently generating your input matrix, and how you want to use your output matrix, could help.

Comment: the view matrix IS the look_at matrix.